# How to find prime numbers between two integers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

https://prnt.sc/fsx2vm

What is the quickest way to find the number of primes between two given integers?

Comment: is your question strictly about between 30 and 50 or for any arbitrary integers $n<m$?

Comment: Any composite number in such range is divided by $2,3,5$ or $7$, hence we expect to have $$20\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{5}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{7}\right)\approx 4.5 $$ prime numbers in such range.

Comment: And they actually are $\{31,37,41,43,47\}$.

Comment: For many reasons it is better to write your Question so that the body is as self-contained as possible.  Asking Readers to follow a link without spelling out what they should expect to find there is a poor practice.  Mathematical expressions can be posted here -- see [this introduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: @Dando18 no, for any arbitrary integers.

Comment: @hardmath Understood

Answer (score 1):

For large numbers you should use a computer.  In *Mathematica* `PrimePi[x]` gives the number of primes less than or equal to `x`.  Hence:

```
PrimePi[50] - PrimePi[30]
```

$5$

And in $0.00824$ seconds we find, for example:

```
PrimePi[500000000] - PrimePi[400000000]
```

$5019541$

Comment: Right, this would work. But in a testing environment I don't have access to a PC. Only my calculator

Comment: @RogerRivas unless your calculator has the functions above, the closest you're going to get is using the approximate prime counting function $\widetilde{\pi}(n) = \text{li} (n) = \int_2^n \frac{dt}{\ln t}$ and calculate $\widetilde{\pi}(m) - \widetilde{\pi}(n)$